# ow to separate a string from Scanner and store each word in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java.util.scanner

How to add string from Scanner to ArrayList in split way?

First I tried this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    yourList.add(sc.next());
}
```

But because of sc.next it moves endlessly while I'm hitting enter.
After that I tried something like the following(+scanner+arrayList):

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String [] values = line.split("//s+");
for (String a : values){
    yourList.add(a);
}
```

But it is also wrong. Everything will be in a first index.

As output it should take the String from Scanner (for instance - "I love my job but i am a good lier"), and as output every word should be in a ArrayList.

```
I
love
my 
job
etc..
```

and if I use .size() here, it should be 10.

Comment: `String [] values = line.split("//s+");` should be `String [] values = line.split("\\s+");` (and yes, that matters).

Comment: Did you try  `CTRL + D`?  If you are using a Mac it is `command D`

Comment: No, i didn't use ctrl-d. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
    for(String a: splited){
        yourList.add(a);
    }
    
    System.out.println(yourList);
```

try with this, hope it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is fine.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
     yourList.add(sc.next());
}
```

The trick is to tell `hasNext()` that there are no more entries.  You need to type the control character that signals end-of-file(EOF).

- Eclipse console it is CTRL+Z.
- Unix/Linux it should be CTRL+D.
- Windows cmd window it's CTRL+Z followed by return.
- For IntelliJ it is CTRL + D.
- Other input devices may have different ways to signal EOF.
- On `Mac platforms` you may need to use `⌘` instead of `CTRL`

Signalling EOF during command line input allows an indefinite quantity of input.

Answer (score -1):

In object-oriented programming there is a concept termed *"[blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing))"*.

It happens when a source object can provide dynamic data to another object, and is waiting for data.

An example situation would be a *TCP/IP* connection—a server and a client.
The server will *block*, or wait for data, before sending it to the client.
Thus, if the client makes a call to get data, and the server has none, a *block* will occur—the client will wait.

A similar situation happens with the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class when given the *System.in* as a source.
By default, *blocking* will occur on several of the methods—in this case *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())*, and *[hasNext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())*.

As a note, this will not happen when *Scanner* is sourced a *String*.
For example, this will not *block*.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("I love my job but i am a good lier");
while (scanner.hasNext()) System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Switching to the *[Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())* is a better option, as *blocking* will not occur when a line is submitted.

Additionally, you have the right Java code, it's the *regular expression pattern* that is incorrect.

The concept of writing *regular expression patterns* can be an undertaking in itself—as the syntax can be quite complex, and sometimes almost too archaic to decipher.

I recommend reviewing the Wikipedia article on Regular Expressions, as it provides a full overview of the syntax.
If you're familiar with basic coding syntax, it's not hard to follow.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

In your code, you're using the wrong *solidus* characters.

```java
line.split("//s+");
```

Should be

```java
line.split("\\s+")
```

If I run the following code, I'll get a valid output.

```java
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = input.nextLine();
String [] values = line.split("\\s+");
for (String a : values){
    yourList.add(a);
}
System.out.println(yourList);
```

Input

```
I love my job but i am a good lier
```

Output

```
[I, love, my, job, but, i, am, a, good, lier]
```