# Scanner.hasNext problems in Java

Tags: java

Hello I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my scanner. I've put it into a different class seperate from my code and I still cannot figure it out. Here is that class:

I cannot get the scanner to break once it's reached the end at all. It just won't work.

If I remove the else, the code will break out of the loop. But under the else statement, it just won't stop running and runs forever.

I've tried a forever loop, while loop, and every iteration in between including if and else statements but .hasnextline won't come back as false, in fact I can't even get it to print false.

My input is literally like 3 lines of string from `system.in`.

Can someone please help with this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String r = "";
        System.out.println("Enter string: ");
        for (;;) {
            if (s.hasNextLine()) {
                r += s.nextLine();
            } 
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("DONE " + r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Input never ends. The user could always type more, after all. If you pipe a file in as standard input, it can end, and `hasNextLine()` can return `false`. By default (keyboard input), it never will. What do you imagine 'no more input' would imply? Generally, you use a string that means: I am done, e.g. "Enter string (enter DONE when done): " and you check if the value of `s.nextLine()` is `DONE`. If yes, `break`.

Comment: Try typing a character that is interpreted by the console as end of file.  It could be CTRL-D or CTRL-Z.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76365413/1552534)

Comment: BTW `hasNext` from title is not the same as `hasNextLine` as in the code (first one reads tokens, second lines)